# Updating stock balance in the inventory catalog

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

When updating the stock balance in a catalog 
I have found this pipeline to help me do that.

**UpdateItemAvailabilityPipeline**

In order to use that I need to know the name 
of the product catalog, the productId (and if 
applicable, the variantId) and what amount to 
change the current stock balance with.

Unfortunatly what I have to work with is only 
one of those three, the productId. Instead of 
the product catalog name I have a name for the 
inventory catalog and instead of the number to 
change the stock balance with I have a number 
to set the stock balance to.

I could of cause fetch the current stock balance
from the database and calculate the difference 
to what it needs to be but if I don't have to 
do that extra database call, all the better.
And I still would need a way to get the product
catalog name from the inventory catalog name.

In order to avoid that I wonder:

Is there a pipeline that I could use that let 
me set a fix number directly in the inventory 
catalog without going through the product 
catalog?

Comment: Why you have these constraints? No product catalog name available and balance delta?

Comment: The system that feed my code with information does not know the name of the product catalog, just the inventory catalog name and it sends the acctual quantity it have, not a delta since it does not know how many items the store think it have.

Answer (score 5):

There's no simple "Set product X to inventory Y" command or pipeline, but here's how we've done it. I've included stubs for handling variants, but not the code that actually loads the variant.

I preferred a pipeline, but I'll just delimit the blocks with comments to keep things simple. The pipeline was invoked once for each inventory update from a Command using a transaction.

It also assumes that the `InventorySet` has already been found and added to the context (we only do this once, so it's not part of this pipeline).

Yes, it's a fair bit of code unfortunately, but it does all the things that the BizFX UI does when you associate a product to an inventory set.

```
public class UpdateInventoryArgument
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

//////////////////////////////////
// ResolveSellableItemBlock

// Inject
IFindEntityPipeline findEntityPipeline;

var sellableItemId = $"{CommerceEntity.IdPrefix<SellableItem>()}{arg.ProductId}";
var sellableItem = await findEntityPipeline.Run(new FindEntityArgument(typeof(SellableItem), sellableItemId, false), context) as SellableItem;

if (sellableItem == null)
{
    context.Abort(await context.CommerceContext.AddMessage(context.GetPolicy<KnownResultCodes>().Warning, "EntityNotFound",
        new[] { sellableItemId }, $"SellableItem '{sellableItemId}' was not found."), context);
    return null;
}

context.CommerceContext.AddUniqueObjectByType(sellableItem);

ItemVariationComponent itemVariation = null;

// Launch this pipeline with Options, not a Context, so that future blocks
// don't accidentally get the previous interation's variant
if (itemVariation != null)
{
    context.CommerceContext.AddUniqueObjectByType(itemVariation);
}

//////////////////////////////////
// ResolveInventoryInformationBlock

// Inject
IGetInventoryInformationPipeline getInventoryInformationPipeline;

var sellableItem = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<SellableItem>();
var itemVariation = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<ItemVariationComponent>();

var inventoryInformation = await getInventoryInformationPipeline.Run(new SellableItemInventorySetArgument(sellableItem.Id, arg.InventorySetId)
{
    VariationId = itemVariation != null ? itemVariation.Id : null
}, context);

if (inventoryInformation == null)
{
    string inventoryInformationId = $"{arg.InventorySetId.SimplifyEntityName()}-{sellableItem.ProductId}";
    if (itemVariation != null)
    {
        inventoryInformationId += $"-{itemVariation.Id}";
    }

    inventoryInformation = new InventoryInformation
    {
        Id = $"{CommerceEntity.IdPrefix<InventoryInformation>()}{inventoryInformationId}",
        FriendlyId = inventoryInformationId,
        InventorySet = new EntityReference(arg.InventorySetId, ""),
        SellableItem = new EntityReference(sellableItem.Id, ""),
        VariationId = itemVariation != null ? itemVariation.Id : null
    };

    inventoryInformation.GetComponent<TransientListMembershipsComponent>().Memberships.Add(CommerceEntity.ListName<InventoryInformation>());
}

context.CommerceContext.AddUniqueObjectByType(inventoryInformation);

////////////////////////
// UpdateInventoryInformationBlock

var inventoryInformation = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<InventoryInformation>();

entoryInformation = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<InventoryInformation>();

if (inventoryInformation == null)
{
    return Task.FromResult((UpdateInventoryArgument)null);
}

inventoryInformation.Quantity = arg.Quantity;

return Task.FromResult(arg);

//////////////////////
// PersistInventoryInformationPipeline

// Inject
ICreateRelationshipPipeline createRelationshipPipeline;
IPersistEntityPipeline persistEntityPipeline;

var inventoryInformation = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<InventoryInformation>();
var sellableItem = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<SellableItem>();
var itemVariation = context.CommerceContext.GetObject<ItemVariationComponent>();

if (inventoryInformation == null)
{
    context.Abort(await context.CommerceContext.AddMessage(context.GetPolicy<KnownResultCodes>().Error, "EntityNotFound",
        new object[0], $"InventoryInformation was not found in context"), context);
    return null;
}

if (sellableItem == null)
{
    context.Abort(await context.CommerceContext.AddMessage(context.GetPolicy<KnownResultCodes>().Error, "EntityNotFound",
        new object[0], $"SellableItem was not found in context"), context);
    return null;
}

var isNew = inventoryInformation.IsPersisted == false;

await persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(inventoryInformation), context);

if (isNew)
{
    await createRelationshipPipeline.Run(new RelationshipArgument(arg.InventorySetId, inventoryInformation.Id, "InventorySetToInventoryInformation"), context);

    (itemVariation != null ? itemVariation.GetComponent<InventoryComponent>() : sellableItem.GetComponent<InventoryComponent>())
        .InventoryAssociations.Add(new InventoryAssociation
        {
            InventoryInformation = new EntityReference(inventoryInformation.Id, ""),
            InventorySet = new EntityReference(arg.InventorySetId, "")
        });

    await persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(sellableItem), context);
}

return arg;
```